# Why don't my docs have anchored headings on readthedocs?

Tags: read-the-docs, mkdocs

I'm using mkdocs to build the hendrix docs from markdown.

When shown on [readthedocs](http://hendrix.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), the documents don't have anchor links for the headings.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a standard feature of Markdown and therefore, is not supported out-of-the-box. However, you can easily enable it with an included Markdown extension. In your `config.yaml` file, include the following:

```
markdown_extensions:
    - toc:
        permalink: True
```

The [docs](http://www.mkdocs.org/user-guide/configuration/#markdown_extensions) explain more about this setting if you are interested.